# Spring, service call from within service

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-mvc, service, web

I have a spring MVC application setup which provides web services. It has Authentication, ACl's, caching etc..

Key question: call of services from within other services.
I am required to implement a setup which will require a full cycle for such calls, including Access Control and Caching support.

Is it possible to implement this? if so please guide me through because I am stuck with getting a solution..

Comment: Way too broad of a question, the short answer is yes, but the long answer is it seems like you're going to fall into an extremely thick service layer.  This leads to code that is hard to test and prone to bugs.

Comment: Hmm.. I was thinking if using JNDI can be of any use? I am not even sure if this is a valid or correct architecture for any web service based application..

Comment: web service usually either uses SOAP or is RESTful.  i.e. You either send the web service xml, it does something with it, and sends you a response back, or you excute a POST / GET to something like /someService/findAll/customers and based on the URL passed, the web service does something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am required to implement a setup which will require a full cycle for
>   such calls, including Access Control and Caching support

Both of these sound like cross cutting concerns which you can handle using Spring AOP. For example Spring 3.1 provides a cache abstraction which will allow you to annotate a service method as `@Cache`. Spring will then take care of looking up the result in your configured cache provider.

In addition Spring security will provide you with the `@Secured` annotation which can be used to limit who can call service methods.

If you use these aspects you can avoid creating a service layer filled with code which does the same thing in lots of different places.

For more information check out the docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) and [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-method-security)